# Code Sorcery cross compile give gc1plus

Tags: eclipse, sorcery

Im trying to cross compile using CS-Lite (arm-none-linux-gnueabi) using eclipse on a linux platform. when i build the project i get the following error for every .cpp file:

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -I../include -I../../com.sdk/include -I../../dev.sdk/include -I../../iop.v0.sdk/include -I../../ugv_v0.95.sdk/include -I../include/thread  -g -Wall  -o "Debug/Driver.o" -c "../src/Driver.cpp"

**arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory**

I have set the environment path correct, my makefile sets CXX to arm-none-linux-gnueabi++ but it continues to fail.

The strange thing is that I can type 'make' from a shell, and it builds fine.

What am I missing in the eclipse setup?

UPDATE:
Just to further confuse things, I can type the exact command that appears in the eclipse console into a shell window and it executes perfectly.

I dont understand the error message.. why is "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++" trying to execute "cc1plus"

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Stupid mistake. When I entered the path for the compiler in the eclipse settings, i use ~/path _to_tools instead of /home/realypath to tools!